# jQuery Validation plugin, $("form").submit wont validate the form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form :

```
 <form id="sForm">
   <input type=text id="msg">
   <input type="button" id="cli">
 </form>
```

And in the script file,I write something:

```
 $("#sForm").validate(
      rules:{msg:{required:true}},
      message:{msg:{required:"please input msg"}}
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
               error.insertAfter(element)
      }
 );
```

When I use submit 
`$("#sForm").submit()` 
the error message displayed on the form,but it still submited.
When I user click function like:
   `$("#cli").click()` 
It succeeds!
What happened?

Comment: The code, as you've written it, totally breaks the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please show a jsFiddle demo where `$("#cli").click()` could make this succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems, any one of these will break the jQuery Validate plugin...

1)  You need to add a set of braces, `{ }`, around your options:

```
$("#sForm").validate({
    // your options
});
```

2)  Your `messages` option is misspelled as `message`.

3)  You are missing a comma after your `messages` option.

4)  Your input elements **must** contain unique `name` attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="msg" id="msg">
```

5)  If you change your input `type="button"` into a `type="submit"`, you won't have to worry about using a `click` or `submit` handler function.  The plugin will capture the `submit` event automatically.

```
<input type="submit" id="cli">
```

**Working code**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // <- ensure the DOM is ready

    $("#sForm").validate({  // <- the braces were missing
        rules: {
            msg: {  // <-  "msg" is supposed to be the name attribute
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: { // <- this was misspelled as "message"
            msg: {
                required: "please input msg"
            }
        },  // <-  this comma was missing
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML Markup**:

```
<form id="sForm">
    <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" />
    <input type="submit" id="cli" />
</form>
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/kPKqQ/

Comment: +1 Wonderful.  I was busy in creating the fiddle.  However your answer is well explained.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem.  You can't use **`id`** in validate method.  *So change your HTML to use **name** attribute*

```
<form id="sForm">
   <input type=text name="msg">
   <input type="submit" name="cli">  <!--since form submission, change it-->
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$("#sForm").validate({
      rules:{'msg':{required:true}},  //REPRESENT NAME ATTRIBUTE NOT ID
      messages:{'msg':{required:"please input msg"}},
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
               error.insertAfter(element)
      }
 });
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fY2xm/12/)